# ok to overwrite to declared : char * a = "abc";?

Tags: c

it is suggested that if a buffer is declared like this:

```
char * a = "one";
```

it should not be over-written again.

```
a = "two";
a = "three";
a = "ab";
```

why would this be a bad thing ?

because this seems to be accepted by most people.

```
char * a = "";
a = "abc";
```

if this is ok. why should the upper examples be not okay ?

Comment: Who said it will be a bad thing? Looks OK to me. You have misunderstood the concept of the string literals being read-only.

Comment: It's read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning `a` to point to a *different* string literal is not the problem; what you've written is fine.

What's not fine is attempting to overwrite string literal that `a` *points to*.  IOW, given the line

```
char * a = "abc";
```

any of the following would result in *undefined behavior*, meaning your code may crash, or it may work, or it may corrupt other data:

```
a[0] = 'A';
strcpy( a, "foo" );
*a = *a + 1;
```

etc.

If you know `a` is only ever going to point to a string literal, it's better to declare it as `const`:

```
const char * a = "abc";
```

You can still assign `a` to point to different string literals:

```
a = "foo";
a = "bar";
```

but if you try to modify what `a` points to, the compiler will yell at you.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly ok to rewrite your `char *variable` with any other `"string"`

But keep in mind that strings written like this are constants, and so are stored within the binary part of your application, increasing its size.

Also, having strings dispersed in your application makes its maintenance a lot harder. You should concentrate all your strings into a single `<headerfile.h>` file and include that file.

Then use the constants to refer to the strings.

Answer (score 0):

`char * a = "one";` is basically equivalent to

```
char const * a = "one";
```

This means `a` is modifiable but not the string `a` points to. So modifying `a` as per the requirement of the code is not bad a practice.